# How do I clone the whole Project and export into different organizations?

Tags: import, export, clone

Could we copy project between different organizations? I mean clone that not only the repo, included everything. Meaning - Boards with wiki,work items and pipelines with build and release.
Thank for your support.

I googled and no answer exactly.